# Redefined copy constructor no getting executed

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I have declared a class below is header file:

```
class Complex
{
private:
    int real;
    int imaginary;

public:

    Complex(); // no arg contructor
    Complex(int,int); // 2 - args constructor
    Complex(const Complex& temp);  // copy constructor
};
```

No I am trying to declare copy constructor again,I know it works but wanted to have some more functionality but its not working when I am including its code in implementation file.Here is code from implementation file.

```
Compelx::Complex(const Complex& temp) // copy constructor 
{
    real = 2*temp.real;
    imaginary =2*temp.imaginary;
}
```

In the `main()` I have following code

```
Complex a,b;

a.setReal(10);
cout<<a.getReal()<<endl;

b=a; // problem is here, copy constructor(that is redefined one) is not being executed.

b.print();
```

Copy constructor is not executing instead I am getting following error:

> 1>  Complex.cpp   1>Complex.cpp(21): error C2653: 'Compelx' : is not a
>   class or namespace name   1>Complex.cpp(21): error C2226: syntax error :
>   unexpected type 'Complex'   1>Complex.cpp(22): error C2143: syntax error
>   : missing ';' before '{'   1>Complex.cpp(22): error C2447: '{' : missing
>   function header (old-style formal list?) 1>  main.cpp   1>  Generating
>   Code...
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: You do know that C++ have [complex numbers in the standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex)?

Comment: ``b=a;`` doesn't call copy constructor but operator=, expect when constructing an object.

Comment: I did not know but that's not the point ,I was asked to work on it @JoachimPileborg

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Not with integer parts.

Comment: That copy constructor is broken, btw. Some situations allows an optimiser to skip a copy, and this copy constructor will cause weird results because skipping it leaves a different object than you get when you invoke it.

Comment: Y NO ANSWERS THAT MENTION BOTH THE SPELLING AND OPERATOR=?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a spelling mistake, try replacing

```
Compelx::Complex(const Complex& temp) // copy constructor
```

with

```
Complex::Complex(const Complex& temp) // copy constructor
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using a copy-assignment operator, not a copy constructor. A copy constructor call would look like:

```
Complex b(a);
```

What you are calling has the signature:

```
Complex& operator=(const Complex& rhs);
```

Comment: A copy constructor could also looks like ``Complex b=a;``

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Compelx
>
>
> Complex
> ```

See the difference.

Answer (score 2):

This statement is an assignment, and you have not provided an implementation for the copy-assignment operator: `Complex& operator=(const Complex&)`. With the [copy&swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) you can reuse your copy-constructor to implement that operator.